# Вычислить Сколько тратится трафика на Запрос. Андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

Делаю простой запрос на сервер на андроид с помошью OkHttp 3. Как можно вычислить сколько на это тратиться трафик? Сколько загружено и наоборот. Как можно реализовать?